# How do I drop to a shell after exiting a command I started by scripting tmux?

Tags: shell, scripting, tmux

I'm following [this tutorial](http://tofu.org/drupal/node/183) for scripting the creation of tmux windows.

```
tmux new-window t $SESSION:0 -k -n MAIN 'cd ~/main/ && perl -Ilib myapp'
```

sometimes I kill myapp after I've started tmux, I want to drop back to a shell in that directory, but instead this kills the window entirely. What is the best way to fix this? I think at least one answer involves running a shell and having that shell run commands, but I'm not sure on the best way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 4):

```
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:0 -k -n MAIN 'cd ~/main/ && perl -Ilib myapp; $SHELL'
```

will launch your default shell when the previous commands have terminated (regardless of their return value, i.e. even if you didn't kill them).

If you only want to drop to the shell if the `perl` process was killed or failed (and have the tmux window close if it succeeded), use

```
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:0 -k -n MAIN 'cd ~/main/ && perl -Ilib myapp || $SHELL'
```

Answer (score 0):

`tmux` already opens a shell for you in which it executes the `cd` and `perl` commands. If you don't want to run **another** shell under that, just so that  you continue an interactive session (or prevent the window from closing, without using `set-remain-on-exit`), you can do:

```
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:0 -k -n MAIN
tmux send-keys 'cd ~/main/ && perl -Ilib myapp' C-m
```

If you want another shell under the `tmux`' created shell and want that shell to execute the commands and become interactive (which is different from @n.st answer that runs the shell afterwards), you can do:

```
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:0 -k -n MAIN 'bash --init-file <(echo "cd ~/main/ && perl -Ilib myapp")'
```

and if it is a problem that that `bash` has an incomplete environment do something like:

```
tmux new-window -t $SESSION:0 -k -n MAIN 'bash --init-file <(echo "source ~/.bashrc; cd ~/main/ && perl -Ilib myapp")'
```